# multiple values for one key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, split, keyvaluepair

I've got a dictionary of unique id's (strings), and values for each of these id's (also strings). The problem is that some of the keys have multiple values separated by commas. I can't think of how to use string manipulation to split them based on commas and still have them assigned to their key.

for example...

```
'abcde': 'abc,def'
```

and I would like it to be:

```
'abcde': 'abc'
'abcde': 'def'
```

any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Bro, add some more information, what is your input, what do you expect. EXAMPLES!

Comment: This makes no sense. It's like asking "I want to define a function f so that f(1)=12 and f(1)=34 too."

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `split`?

```
>>> my_dict = {'key1':'apple,banana,cherry', 'key2':'date,fig', 'key3':'grape,honeydew'}
>>> new_dict = {k, v.split(',') for k, v in my_dict.items()}:
>>> new_dict
{'key1': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
 'key2': ['date', 'fig'],
 'key3': ['grape', 'honeydew']}
```